# Carousel in Laravel 4 does not show as expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, foreach, carousel

I want to create an carousel slider using laravel and bootstrap.

Here is step I follow:

1. Upload and save image to database => success.
2. Loop throw  the table to get image path from database then put it into carousel => success
3. Display slider => Problem here. It is not problem of Js and Jquery. If I call the image by path, for example:

   ```
     {{ HTML::image('img/slides/1.jpg', '...') }}
   ```

I can slide throw images.

But when I put them in to an foreach loop, the image's displayed, but I can not slide throw them.

My Code

```
         @foreach($banners as $banner)

            <div class="carousel-inner">

               <div class="item active">
                 {{  HTML::image($banner->image, '...')}}
               </div>
            </div>

        @endforeach
```

why isn't this code working?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is creating multiple `carousel-inner`, that's wrong. You must have one `carousel-inner` and multiple `item`. OTOH you need to set to `active` just one `item`, not all of them.

[Bootstrap Carousel example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-examples).

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    @foreach($banners as $i => $banner)
        <div class="item{{ ($i) ? '' : ' active' }}">
            {{ HTML::image($banner->image, '...') }}
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant solution! Thank you very much.

Comment: @LuckyLuke Glad I could help. Please mark it as the correct answer if this solves your problem.